# What is a noun expressing a very young person who has advanced skills even higher than adults?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Mozart composed from the age of five and performed before European royalty.

Not many grownups can do that.

**What is a noun expressing a very young person who has advanced skills even higher than adults?**

Comment: Is there a single word in Vietnamese?

Comment: @JamesK, "Thần đồng âm nhạc" for example

Comment: A dictionary will give "Thần đồng" = "Infant prodigy" or "Child prodigy" 
 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/th%E1%BA%A7n_%C4%91%E1%BB%93ng https://vdict.com/Th%E1%BA%A7n%20%C4%91%E1%BB%93ng,2,0,0.html

Comment: I'm sure there's no English word that unambiguously identifies a child as having "advanced skills" even ***higher*** than (most) adults. But we do have **precocious** - *(of a child) having developed certain abilities or inclinations **at an earlier age than is usual or expected**.*

Comment: Gifted? When it's used with adults it's usually a euphemism. If you hadn't said *mozart*, I wonder if *savant* would've made it, as when you google *mozart was a*, the second suggestion is the third comment in the answer below: "child prodigy". The first is *kapellmeister* "the leader or conductor of an orchestra or choir."

Comment: Did you consult any dictionaries before asking here?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[Prodigy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prodigy):

> Someone with a very great ability that usually shows itself when that person is a young child

It should be mentioned that 'child prodigy' is also a noun, but applicable to a young person who is a child (Magnus Carlsen became a Grandmaster, the highest norm of Chess when he was 13 years old and thus was labelled a child prodigy).

Comment: what about "child protégé"?

Comment: That's a different meaning, it sounds similar but it's not related. *A person who is guided and supported by an older and more experienced or influential person.*

Comment: @Tom  You mean *child prodigy*

Comment: I think "prodigy" and "protege" are the same

Comment: @Tom No, they have different meanings.

Comment: @Tom they are similar sounding words, but I wouldn't be surprised if they shared an identical or nearly identical pronunciation in some accents. It may even be subtle enough difference with certain accents that a non-native speakers may have trouble hearing a distinction (or even native speakers unaware of both words). But I think ultimately what you have found is an [eggcorn](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/eggcorn)

Comment: "protégé" is not really English. It is clearly a borrowed word due to the accents. It is like the phrase "Faux Pas". Understood by native speakers, but it isn't actually English.

Comment: @Nelson Protégé is certainly a word in English. Similar to countless other words that existed in other languages first. "Protégé" also exists in every dictionary.

Comment: As an example: ''Von Neumann was a child prodigy. When he was six years old, he could divide two eight-digit numbers in his head[35][36] and could converse in Ancient Greek.''

Comment: @BigMistake You're right - but it's a moot point.  Tom is simply incorrect, and "protégé"  is neither a synonym for "prodigy" nor a valid answer to the OP's question.

Comment: This answer is simply **wrong** or let's say, not as good as the actual answer, precocious.  A prodigy *can be* and *often is* a young person,  but that's simply nothing more than a common usage. ) Precocious means precocious, end of story, exactly as the OP is asking. (Indeed ... note the common phrase "child prodigy", which you use with prodigy to point out that you mean someone who is precocious.)

Comment: @Fattie: This answer is no more wrong than the "precocious" answer. "Precocious" means "developed much earlier than usual", but it _doesn't_ convey the "skills even higher than adults" part of the question. "Prodigy" _does_ convey that, even if it requires clarification that it's a young person.

Comment: @Fattie The OP specifically asked for a noun, which "precocious" is not.  If you want to be pedantic then "child prodigy" is more correct than just "prodigy", but "prodigy" is a fair answer.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain you're right - OP asked for a noun, good call

Answer (score 22):

**Wunderkind** ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wunderkind))

> one who succeeds in a competitive or highly difficult field or profession at an early age

This is a German loanword, with the original pronunciation, and the classic example is Mozart.

The calque *wonderkid* also exists, but is a primarily-British word for an excellent young athlete.  [The Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wonderkid) gives a broader definition, but when you look at the list of examples, they’re all about athletes.

Comment: **вундеркинд** in cyrillic ...

Answer (score 9):

##### Precocious ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precocious))

> (especially of children) showing mental development or achievement much earlier than usual

Other answers provide nouns for that young person.  If you need an adjective, this would be your best choice.  "Prodigy" as a noun describes the young person, but the adjective "prodigious" merely describes something which is exceptionally large or well-developed and does not reflect the OP's requirement that the development is exceptional for their age.

Comment: "Precocious" has a negative connotation, alluded to in the dictionary you refer to: "A precocious child behaves as if they are much older than they are e.g. 'a precocious little brat'". E.g. see [this SO answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300527/whats-a-similar-word-to-precocious-with-a-positive-connotation#:~:text=Precocious%2C%20per%20its%20definition%2C%20describes,saying%20it%20out%20of%20spite). "Prodigy" is a less ambiguous option unless you want to include the negative connotation.

Comment: Precocious has no negative connotation, at all, unless it is used in a snide manner.  Exactly the same applies to words like "smart" or "achiever".

Comment: @ReversedEngineer Not really. As the dictionary says, it doesn't in itself have a negative connotation - any negative connotation is purely in the child *behaving* as if they are older (and specifically behaving as if they have the same rights as if they are older).  In a positive context (for example skill at sport or music) there is no ambiguity and no negative connotation.  And as I said, if you want an adjective then it really is the only available option - "prodigy" is a perfectly good noun, but the derived adjective does not have the same meaning at all.

Comment: @Fattie Thanks - I was looking for an example of another similar word, and the use of "smart" in "watch that smart mouth, kid" illustrates it perfectly.  ReversedEngineer, is "smart" also a word we should avoid due to those negative connotations?

Comment: @Graham there are plenty of words that only come up in certain contexts and therefore have an implied meaning. Given that I have never looked up the word "precocious" in a dictionary and I have _never_ heard it in a positive context, I have always assumed that it was a negative word; regardless of the strict definition, as a native speaker, I would interpret it as you insulting the person

Comment: @roganjosh Sure there are, but the fact that the negative version is second on the list of meanings tells you that this is not the case.  Obviously it is a meaning (although of course it's only as a modifier for "brat", not in itself an insult), but it's not the only one. If your assumptions disagree with the dictionary definition, I'd suggest that's a you problem and not an everyone-else problem. ;)

Comment: I think whether 'precocious' is a bad, neutral, or good thing depends a lot on your ideas about raising children.  I think (hope) less people think it's a bad thing as time goes on.

Comment: @roganjosh Conversely, I don’t recall ever hearing anyone use _precocious_ in a negative sense, only as a positive description of a child whose abilities exceeded those of their peers of the same age. I wasn’t aware this was a dialectal issue, but the comments on the question linked to in the first comment under this answer indicate that perhaps it is – it’s apparently likely to be used negatively in the UK (and South Africa, going by Reversed Engineer’s profile location), but not in the US. I suppose I’ve not heard Brits use the word much.

Comment: In Australia, I would say precocious has mostly negative connotations, using the word precocious as a compliment would sound archaic to me. Might be weak support for a dialect distinction.

Comment: Simply wanted to add, that in the excellent book Matilda by Roald Dahl, which is centered around an exceptionally intelligent child. Precocious is the word Miss Honey uses to describe Matilda and it is meant entirely positive :)

Comment: Bit late here: For me maybe more 'gifted' than 'precocious' and gifted is mostly shorn of negative connotation. The precocious again for me (Ontario, Canada) means the kid who sits and listens quietly to the adults (as long as their parent doesn't shoo them away for certain subjects), they become precocious in the negative way if they more than rarely chime in with their own advice again subject appropriate (some questions/questioning though being appropriate).

Answer (score 5):

**whizz-kid** (British) or **whiz-kid** (American) is also listed in `dict-freedict-deu-eng` as synonym for *Wunderkind*.. [fixed Br./Am. mixup]

Comment: A whizz-kid could also be used for  a young adult. The proper name of the online dictionary is *The Free Dictionary*

Comment: @Mari-LouA: dict-freedict-deu-eng: This is the German-English dictionary from the [FreeDict](https://freedict.org/) project.

Comment: Why not add the link with the definition/synonyms in the answer itself?

Comment: .. because I used a command line tool for these downloadable dictionaries and I can't find a web service right now.

Comment: I think you've got that backward: double zed variant is British. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whizz-kid

Comment: thanks @bishop yeah you're right, fixed it 

Answer (score 1):

A more specific version is "**enfant terrible**" (French, lit. "*terrible child*").
While originally having the meaning of a child who embarrasses their parents by being very blunt and straightforward, [now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enfant_terrible)

> it implies a successful, and often young, "genius" who is very unorthodox, striking, and in some cases, offensive, or rebellious

While this might not work very well in your specific example, it can be useful for others, and I think makes a good addition to the existing answers.

Comment: Why downvote?  Correct.

Comment: Not the OP's question...

Comment: @Raydot Not *necessarily* an answer to the OP's question, as I pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

like *savant*, or *prodigy*?

**sa·vant**
/saˈvän(t),säˈvänt/
*noun*

> a very learned or talented person, especially one distinguished in a particular field of science or the arts.

**prod·i·gy**

/prädəjē/

*noun*

> a person, especially a young one, endowed with exceptional qualities or abilities.

Comment: Prodigy has already been suggested.

Comment: What Mari-Lou said, so please [edit] your answer to either expand on "prodigy" to make it significantly better than Rakib's answer, or remove "prodigy" from yours. Also, please include your source for the definitions and pronunciations.